# Custom Style Calendar with Google Calendar Events

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, google-calendar-api

If a client presented a project to make a webpage that displays a custom-styled calendar (with their google calendar events), what would be the best route to go? I'm trying to get started on a project to display a calendar on my tv via a Raspberry Pi. I've tried to search for everything I can on the topic, and it's been difficult to find anything that's clear enough to give me some direction. I figured asking the question on here may draw some attention from more experienced programmers. Much Thanks! I attached an image that's a rough example of what I'm hoping to create:

[image: calendar]

Comment: It's just a rough idea. Ideally I'd like to add an animation on the right side that switches back and forth from the calendar days to events of 5 days or so. I'll try to mock up an example of what that would hopefully look like.

Comment: Shouldn't be too difficult to find base calendar code that has hooks for date selection that you can use to query for events. Beyond that a lot depends on how feature rich they want it. Hard to beat fullcalendar for features

Comment: It'd be great to find something that just requires me to put in the google calendar url to sync it, so all I have to do is the css. Haven't found anything like that yet